# Not the sort of the widget tree. TreeBehavior

Tags: php, cakephp

The controller `Controller/WidgetsController.php` using this function:

```
public function admin_moveup($id, $step = 1) {

    $widget = $this->Widget->findById($id);
    if (!isset($widget['Widget']['id'])) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for Widget'), 'alert', array('class' => 'alert-error'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Widget->Behaviors->load('Tree', array(
        'scope' => array(
            'Widget.block_id' => $widget['Widget']['block_id'],
        ),
    ));
    if ($this->Widget->moveUp($id, $step)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Moved up successfully'), 'alert', array('class' => 'alert-success'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Could not move up'), 'alert', array('class' => 'alert-error'));
    }
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

But move up returns the error: `Could not move up!`

Tracing it, I found out that in class `TreeBehavior` `(Lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/TreeBehavior.php)` executing `function moveup` from line 570 returns null!

What could be the problem?

Comment: Either the node is already the first child, or the tree is not valid. Check your table (`select id, parent_id, lft, rght from widgets order by lft`), [recover](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior::recover) it if necessary, and failing that _debug the tree behavior and find out why_.

Answer (score 0):

It problem on `'Widget.block_id' => $widget['Widget']['block_id']` conditions, which show multiple parent's children. But move up work between same parent's children order by `lft`.